# Firebase AB Test has 0 users

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We've started an AB test using Firebase remote config. It's been over 24 hours, and it's showing "Total Users: 0" when there should have been tens of thousands of DAUs assigned to each variant.

- how long does it take for data to come in?
- is there any way to tell if it's running?
- If it remains at zero, what are the potential root causes? Why are people not being assigned to test variants?

Comment: What happens when you follow the steps to [validate your experiment on a test device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/abtest-config#validate_your_experiment_on_a_test_device)? Are you able to receive different variants on a test device?

Comment: @Jeff nope! I get all the remote configs, including new ones I add. However, I never get the value from the AB test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution. A few dumb mistakes, but they are easy to miss because the remote config works fine without fixing them.

- Ensure you upgrade Firebase SDK/pod to 4.5 or later. Earlier versions have an identical API but won't serve AB tests values (only remote config values)
- Ensure you call fetchWithExpirationDuration AFTER you call `FIRApp configure`
- Verify a draft AB test is working before shipping to app store. Some tips for doing this:

  - Pass 0 for expiration in `fetchWithExpirationDuration` when in debug mode so it's forced to fetch new values every time (it will cache by default).
  - Setup remote config in debug mode (code below)
  - Instructions from Google on how to verify: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/abtest-config#validate_your_experiment_on_a_test_device

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    FIRRemoteConfigSettings* remoteConfigSettings = [[FIRRemoteConfigSettings alloc] initWithDeveloperModeEnabled:YES];
    [FIRRemoteConfig remoteConfig].configSettings = remoteConfigSettings;
#endif
```