# Firebase AB testing SDK error: abt.AbtException. Events collected in console, but 0 user included

Tags: android, firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I'm setting up a remote config AB testing with self-defined events. 
I can see my events in Dashboard/Events/DebugView as well as GCP Query.

However, every experiment includes 0 user after several days and stops with an error.

I checked the logcat as app running,  there was an firebase SDK (abt.AbtException )error alerted :

```java
E/FirebaseRemoteConfig: Could not update ABT experiments.
   com.google.firebase.abt.AbtException: The Analytics SDK is not available. Please check that the Analytics SDK is included in your app dependencies.
       at com.google.firebase.abt.FirebaseABTesting.zzg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.abt.FirebaseABTesting.replaceAllExperiments(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.FirebaseRemoteConfig.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.zza.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

My SDK versions are as follows:

```java
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:16.3.0'
```

Also, firebase-config version is 16.4.0 , I'm sure it supports AB testing.

I have referred to this Q&A but none of them could solve my problem

- [AB testing config applied but firebase console show 0 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444991/ab-testing-config-applied-but-firebase-console-show-0-users)
- [Firebase AB Test has 0 users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915388/firebase-ab-test-has-0-users)
- [Firebase Remote Config A/B testing shows no results after 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311141/firebase-remote-config-a-b-testing-shows-no-results-after-24-hours)

Updating SDKs to the latest versions could be a lot risky.

I wonder how I could solve this problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I came across this error on my project and was missing the required dependency on `app > build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...   
   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')  
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
   ...   
}
```

This does not specifically solve the problem that the OP had, but the same error is thrown if you are missing the required dependencies.

Also as a side note, `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')` automatically configures other firebase-related dependencies. If you do not want that and have an error similar to OP, use this link as a reference on available libraries and versions and try to update your Analytics version if possible: [available libraries | firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update the analytics sdk (and core) to the latest version to see if this solves your issue?